# Where is this TypeError coming from? (Using actin for stellar activity indices) TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not bool

Tags: python, astronomy, fits

I'm using a package that can be found here: https://github.com/gomesdasilva/ACTIN to find activity indices for a binary system. Intially, I've run the code on a standalone test file on spyder and it all seems to work fine:

```
import actin.actin as actin

actin.actin("C://Users//Rp199/Desktop//J0608_59_harps_2018//HARPS.2019-08-22T08_37_32.360_s1d_A.fits",
            calc_index=['I_CaII'], rv_in=None,
            config_file="C:\\Users\\Rp199\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\actin\config_lines.txt",
            save_output=True, ln_plts=False, obj_name=False, targ_list='J0608-59',
            del_out=False, frac=True, test=False, save_plots=False)

EXECUTING ACTIN_FILE
--------------------
Executing: check_targ
Targets = J0608-59
Object = J0608-59

LOADING DATA FROM CONFIG FILE
-----------------------------
CaIIK
CaIIH
CaIIR1
CaIIR2

READING DATA FROM FILE:
-----------------------
Working folder: C://Users//Rp199/Desktop//J0608_59_harps_2018\
Reading file:   HARPS.2019-08-22T08_37_32.360_s1d_A.fits
Telescope:  ESO-3P6
Instrument: HARPS
Object:     J0608-59
*** WARNING: Could not find or open:
*** C://Users//Rp199/Desktop//J0608_59_harps_2018\HARPS.2019-08-22T*_ccf_*_A.fits
*** WARNING: No CCF data available.
*** WARNING: Could not find or open:
*** C://Users//Rp199/Desktop//J0608_59_harps_2018\HARPS.2019-08-22T*_bis_*_A.fits
*** WARNING: No BIS data available.
*** ERROR: No rv data available to calibrate wavelength.

---------------------------------
Fractional pixels:  True
Files analysed:     1
Save output:        True
Elapsed time:       0.0013 min
```

The output states it doesn't have the CCF and BIS files which is correct.

I now try to run the code on another fits file, however, in this folder there are the BIS and CCF files and receive the output:

```
READING DATA FROM FILE:
-----------------------
Working folder: C://Users//Rp199//Desktop//DATA_NEW\
Reading file:   HARPS.2019-01-20T05_16_29.969_s1d_A.fits
Telescope:  ESO-3P6
Instrument: HARPS
Object:     J0608-59
CCF file:   HARPS.2019-01-20T05_16_29.969_ccf_G2_A.fits
BIS file:   HARPS.2019-01-20T05_16_29.969_bis_G2_A.fits

Executing check_duplicate:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Rp199\Desktop\actintest.py", line 10, in <module>
    actin.actin("C://Users//Rp199//Desktop//DATA_NEW//HARPS.2019-01-20T05_16_29.969_s1d_A.fits",

  File "C:\Users\Rp199\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\actin\actin.py", line 225, in actin
    output = actin_file(files_list[k][i][j],

  File "C:\Users\Rp199\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\actin\actin.py", line 92, in actin_file
    dupl = ac_save.check_duplicate(data['obj'], data['obs_date'], data['instr'], data['file_type'], save_output)

  File "C:\Users\Rp199\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\actin\actin_files\ac_save.py", line 45, in check_duplicate
    pfile_name = os.path.join(out_dir, obj, file_name)

  File "C:\Users\Rp199\anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 78, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not bool
```

I'm confused as to why this error occurs, especially when testing with the standalone file without any CCF or BIS file in the same folder, there are no errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon careful reading of the traceback one can see that if the `save_output` argument is anything other than `False` it must be a string specifying the output directory. This is non-obvious since it's not written in the docstring and the default value for that argument is `False` suggesting that it can also take `True` as you passed. But the code for this package is doing a number of things non-idiomatically that can lead to other problems. I'll contact its author later if I have time to see if I can offer any suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Yeah I realised shortly after reading the GitHub page that if you want to save the output it says state the path and forgot to edit the post for solved, was just my bad reading and the confusion arose from the successful run in the beginning with a different file. Thank you!